# Figcaption Animation Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dXd26/

The code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <figure class="col-sm-6 item"> 

        <a href="item.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/720x480&text=720x480+Game" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Game"></a>

        <!-- Item Hover Options -->
        <figcaption>
            <!-- Item Title -->
             <h2>Item Title</h2>

            <!-- Item Description -->
            <p>Item Description</p>
            <!-- Item Progress -->
            <div class="progress progress-striped">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-default" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%"> <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>

                </div>
                <!-- END progress bar -->
            </div>
            <!-- END progress div -->
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <!-- END item title figure -->
</div>
```

The issue is that on hover the caption that shows is slightly wider than the image.

How can I fix it so that the width of the caption is correct on all devices??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your CSS like so (remove width 100% and change left/right).

```
figcaption {
  ...
  /* left: 0;
  width: 100%; */
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  ...
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/edYH8/)

Answer (score 1):

When you set `position: absolute;` on the `figcaption`, its width will now be relative to the window instead of the `figure` (its parent element). So `width: 100%;` should be less. Or try adding a margin.